# How do I insert a blank cell into an existing excel worksheet using xlwt?

Tags: python, xlwt

I have an excel sheet with values in some of the cells, and I need to iterate through those cells and for some, insert a blank cell and push all the cells below down one. Can I do that with xlwt? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: no you cannot do that ... you need to read in everything ... then write out everything to a new workbook ...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into win32com from [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) module, you can use COM to interact with Excel. I don't recall a way to move cells down, as @Joran said you would be better off copying your content into a new workbook or a whole new excel document.

[Goermezer Examples](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/category/7/86/192/)

[More Python win32com examples](https://github.com/pythonexcels/examples)

[Python-Excels](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/)